# .Spyder opens a figure instead of absence of plt.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I actually know a problem in Spyder. When I Work with matplotlib.pyplot, it automatically shows the figure without any kind of plt.show(). So when I make many different figures, it always shows them all on the same.
I've recently made a program, which is saving one figure by iteration in an for loop, it also opens a figure and at the end, the loop crashes before ending because of too many figures showed.
I would like to know if someone also knows such problems, because I've encountered the in many computers running spyder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely are running in iPython with Spyder. iPython automatically runs `plt.show()`. Press f6 (default), and see if "execute in current python or iPython console" is selected. If so, check the console, the 'tab' should show a blue icon with "iP" and have 'kernal' (or similar) following it.

Simple fix: switch to "execute in dedicated python console" *or* open a new python console (tab header "python 1")

Source: had same problem.